# Scroll Area in FlowLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a problem with my ScrollLayoutPanel, where after minimizing the window, the scroll area expands a lot, creating a lot of empty space below my items. This also creates a problem where a user minimizes and maximizes the window multiple times, and the current view of the flow layout is randomly somewhere in the middle of the total scroll area. Then a user clicks a button inside the panel and instead of activating it, the panel resets to the top forcing the user to search for the button and clicking it again. I tried suspending the layout when the window is minimized, but it seems that the suspension executes after the damage is done. Is there any ways to fix this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and update your question appropriately. Note that the example should be "minimal", which probably means creating a new test project that omits all the noise from your real project.

Comment: No need, turns out problem was clear enough to understand once i described it to a friend. I'll remember for the future though, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming across this question here's what worked:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    base.WndProc(ref m);

    if (m.Msg == 0x0112)
    {
        if (m.WParam == new IntPtr(0xF020))
        {
            this.buttonsContainer.AutoScroll = false;
            this.buttonsContainer.SuspendLayout();
        }

        if (m.WParam == new IntPtr(0xF120))
        {
            this.buttonsContainer.AutoScroll = true;
            this.buttonsContainer.ResumeLayout();
        }
    }
}
```

What it does is it disables scrolling and suspends layout when the window is being minimized (state `0xF020`) and reverses that when the window is being restored (state `0xF120`)

Comment: It may solve the problem, but there is likely a less convoluted way.